# Lightdm GTK greeter with secondary monitor on the left

Tags: fedora, multi-monitor, lightdm

I am trying to configure the lightdm GTK greeter for a dual-monitor setup, where the secondary monitor is placed on left. I followed [this part of a guide](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/LightDM#LightDM_displaying_in_wrong_monitor) that suggests using the `display-setup-script` config option to run a single-line command and so I did:

```
xrandr --output DVI-D-0 --primary --mode 1920x1080 --pos 1920x0 --right-of HDMI-0 --output HDMI-0 --mode 1920x1080 --pos 0x0 --left-of DVI-D-0
```

But it seems to have no effect as I still have to scroll to the far left of the left monitor to reach my primary monitor that's on the right.

Some places even suggest to put a monitors.xml file inside `/var/lib/lightdm/.config/` but that isn't working either. Is there something else I haven't tried yet?

I am on fedora 26 and using the Awesome WM DE.

Comment: I had similar issues and ultimately decided to simply turn off the second monitor during login: `xrandr --output HDMI-0 --off --output DVI-D-0 --primary`